# libjpeg-turbo java encode jpeg

Tags: java, libjpeg-turbo, turbojpeg

Ive installed libjpeg-turbo on my mac and added the jar and libs to my eclipse project. Im trying to create jpeg byte[] from my bufferedimage:

```
TJCompressor tj = new TJCompressor();
tj.compress(image, TJ.PF_BGR);
```

The error I get is: java.lang.Exception: tjBufSize(): Invalid argument

I use a custom robot to create my bufferedimage with the type TYPE_3BYTE_BGR. I can create a byte[] using ImageIO but its to slow.

I tried to find some tutorials on the java wrapper, but I havnt found any that encode a jpeg from a bufferedimage. I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be passing in the wrong type of argument into the method. You are passing in a pixel format when you should be passing in zero or more flags from the `TJ` class (prefixed with "FLAG_"). The pixel format type will be automatically detected by the `TJCompressor` object.

Make sure you set the chrominance subsampling level and JPEG quality to your desired levels before using the `TJCompressor` as well.

Sample code:

```
TJCompressor tj = new TJCompressor();
tj.setJPEGQuality(75);
tj.setSubsamp(TJ.SAMP_420);
byte[] jpegBytes = tj.compress(image, 0);
```